# Replace the data of AChartEngine's piechart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am drawing piechart using `ACartENgine` . And I want to replace the data of piechart. To replace I called `mSeries.clear();` method to remove all old data and then add new dataset to `mSeries`. 
But my problem is while do this all my `legends` displayed in white color instead of category color. How can I avoid this problem. All I want is replace the data of piechart with new values. Is there any better idea. How can I achieve this? Any one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `set(int index, String title, double value)` method in the `CategorySeries` class that you can use.

Just make sure you are using the latest version available [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).